# How to configure syscache's Region and Expiration using code (not in App.Config xml)

Tags: nhibernate, syscache2, syscache

I'm trying to configure NHibernate's 2nd level cache.
I want to configure by code and not use xml configuration
I've followed most of the tutorial but I can't seem to translate this xml configuration in code:

```
<syscache>
    <cache region="LongTerm" expiration="180" priority="5" />
    <cache region="ShortTerm" expiration="60" priority="3" />
</syscache>
```

How can I configure the syscache region and expiration settings using code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syscache gets the values from the application configuration file. It does not expose any configuration by code.

You can clone it from https://github.com/diegose/NHibernate.Diegose (non-authoritative, but up-to-date) and implement a code api yourself.